# What does this mean "bad operand type String for unary operator ++"

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I can't figure out what's wrong here. my code is supposed to check how many times a state specific appears in a 1 column csv file. I'm trying to avoid having a separate counter for each individual state. My code is below and the error is below that

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class csvtxt {

   public static void main(String a[]){
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String strLine = "";
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      try {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\dbb38\\Downloads\\customers_export_1111 - customers_export_1.csv"));
         while (strLine != null)
         {
            strLine = br.readLine();
            if (strLine==null)
               break;
            sb.append(strLine);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            list.add(strLine);
         }
         String[] state = new String[]{"Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"};
         String[] state1 = new String[]{"Alabama1", "Alaska1", "Arizona1", "Arkansas1", "California1", "Colorado1", "Connecticut1", "Delaware1", "Florida1", "Georgia1", "Hawaii1", "Idaho1", "Illinois1", "Indiana1", "Iowa1", "Kansas1", "Kentucky1", "Louisiana1", "Maine1", "Maryland1", "Massachusetts1", "Michigan1", "Minnesota1", "Mississippi1", "Missouri1", "Montana1", "Nebraska1", "Nevada1", "New Hampshire1", "New Jersey1", "New Mexico1", "New York1", "North Carolina1", "North Dakota1", "Ohio1", "Oklahoma1", "Oregon1", "Pennsylvania1", "Rhode Island1", "South Carolina1", "South Dakota1", "Tennessee1", "Texas1", "Utah1", "Vermont1", "Virginia1", "Washington1", "West Virginia1", "Wisconsin1", "Wyoming1"};
         for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String wordToSearchFor = state[i];
            for (String state2 : list) {
                  if (state2.equals(wordToSearchFor)) {
                     state1[i]++;
                  }
            }
            System.out.println(state[i] + "="  + "["+ state1 +"]");
         }
         //
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
         br.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.err.println("File not found");
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
      }
   }
}
```

This is the error

```
csvtxt.java:34: error: bad operand type String for unary operator '++'
                     state1[i]++;
                              ^
1 error
```

Comment: It means exactly what it  says. Have another look at your code. You're trying to post-increment a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `state1` to be `String[]`. So `state1[i]` refers to a `String`. You are applying the operator `++` to a `String` which is illegal: hence the error.

If you wish to have an integer track the counts then declare an integer array instead:

```
int[] stateCounts = new int[state.length];
```

Then you can happily increment the counts when you find a match:

```
stateCounts[i]++;
```

Comment: ok. How can I count the occurence of each state in the csv file?

Comment: That's really a completely different question than your original one. But I'll add a hint to the answer to get you started.